# Dropwizard 0.8 and Jetty fail return 404 on resources

Tags: java, servlets, jetty, jersey-2.0, dropwizard

I am trying to hook up a dropwizard 0.8.* application, and I have used a hello world starter example.

The code is left untouched and the application starts-up normally.

Though when I try to access the path assigned to the hello world GET request, the browser returns a :

```
HTTP ERROR 404

Problem accessing /hello-world. Reason:

    Not Found
```

This is kinda strange since the app logs say otherwise and return 200 for that request:

```
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [15/Sep/2015:07:33:58 +0000] "GET /hello-world HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.85 Safari/537.36" 0
```

Am I missing anything in terms of configuration or else ? I am running under OSX and google Chrome.

Adding more information I have tried two different hello-world examples and both fail. On top with spring boot and also akka-http I have no problems.

Answer (score 10):

I had the same issue,

While starting the server it says "MutableServletContextHandler@4b2a30d{/application,null,AVAILABLE}"

so try /application/hello-world,

It worked for me. (Credit to my friend who helped me :) )

http://tips.tutorialhorizon.com/2015/10/03/dropwizard-0-8-and-jetty-fail-return-404-on-resources/

Comment: This worked for me! My guess is you're using the [`server: type: simple` config](https://dropwizard.github.io/dropwizard/0.8.2/docs/manual/configuration.html#simple) in your `configuration.yml`. You can customer it with the `applicationContext` config property, also under `server`, for example `applicationContext: /`.

Comment: Ugh, can't edit any more. I meant to say `applicationContextPath`.